# How can set programmatically style to Label in appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I want to set programmatically the font style to Label in one appcelerator application.

So this is:

**socialHistory.tss**

```
".headerTableLabel" : {
    top : "10px",
    color : "#B3B3B3",
    textAlign : "center",
    width: '340px',
    font : {
        fontSize : "20pt",
        fontWeight : "Italic"
    }
}
```

This is my **socialHistory.js**

```
function createHeader(headerText){
   var heading = Ti.UI.createView({
      height:30, top : 15,
      backgroundColor : "#0c7b84"
   });

   var headingText = Ti.UI.createLabel({
       text : headerText,
       classes: 'headerTableLabel'
   });

      heading.add(headingText);

      return heading;
}
```

I want to set programmatically the style of my Label under createLabel method. But it not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
function createHeader(headerText){
   var heading = Ti.UI.createView({
      height:30, top : 15,
      backgroundColor : "#0c7b84"
   });

   var headingText = $.UI.create("Label", {
       classes: 'headerTableLabel'
   );
   headingText.text = headerText;

      heading.add(headingText);

      return heading;
}
```